# How to copy all the files with the same suffix to another directory? - Unix

Tags: linux, file, unix, copy, find

I have a directory with unknown number of subdirectories and unknown level of sub*directories within them. How do I copy all the file swith the same suffix to a new directory?

E.g. from this directory:

```
> some-dir
  >> foo-subdir
    >>> bar-sudsubdir
      >>>> file-adx.txt
  >> foobar-subdir
    >>> file-kiv.txt
```

Move all the *.txt files to:

```
> new-dir
 >> file-adx.txt
 >> file-kiv.txt
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

One option is to use `find`:

```
find some-dir -type f -name "*.txt" -exec cp \{\} new-dir \;
```

`find some-dir -type f -name "*.txt"` would find `*.txt` files in the directory `some-dir`.  The `-exec` option builds a command line (e.g. `cp file new.txt`) for every matching file denoted by `{}`.

Comment: can you explain what the `-exec` option and the multiple slashes `\` please?

Comment: added above.  `{}` and `;` have been escaped. `;` is normally treated by the shell as a command separator.

Comment: You don't need to escape the braces.

Comment: I know that.  Old habits die hard.

Answer (score 4):

Use `find` with `xargs` as shown below:

```
find some-dir -type f -name "*.txt" -print0 | xargs -0 cp --target-directory=new-dir
```

For a large number of files, this `xargs` version is more efficient than using `find some-dir -type f -name "*.txt" -exec cp {} new-dir \;` because `xargs` will pass multiple files at a time to `cp`, instead of calling `cp` once per file. So there will be fewer fork/exec calls with the `xargs` version.